# boost spirit expression grammar issue while creating AST

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to parse expression grammar (with variables) into an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) so that later on I could make a use of this AST and calculate values basing on those expressions (they may be a part of a function for example, so there is no need to store those expressions rather than calculate a value right away).

To my surprise, after handling with loops and instructions (which require nested structures in AST as well), I got nothing but seg faults after trying to parse any expression.. After hours of struggling with this I decided to ask here, because I have no idea what is it (maybe something with the grammar)

This statement-loop part works perfectly well. The struct 'loop' gets as a parameter only a number of repetitions - string so far (later on I want to put an expression here):

```
statement %= loop | inst;
inst %= lexeme[+(char_ - (';'|char_('}'))  )] >> ';'; 
loop = "do("    >   lexeme[+(char_ - "){")] // parse a number of loop repetitions
        >   "){"
        >   *statement > "}"
        ;
```

Structures are like:

```
typedef boost::variant<
    boost::recursive_wrapper<s_loop>
    , std::string> 
s_statement;

struct s_loop
{
    std::string name;                           // tag name 
    //s_expression exp; // TODO
    std::vector<s_statement> children;        // children
};
```

I use recursive wrapper, so I thought that maybe it is because of "deep" wrapping in case of expression-term-factor, why I can't do it. For loop-statement it goes simply like: 
loop --(contains)--> statement (statement may be a loop!)
And in case of expressions it should be finally implemented like:
expression -> term -> factor (factor may be an expression!)

So, to be sure it's because of 'deep' wrapping, I tried with trivial grammar:
expression -> factor (factor may be an expression)

AST structures are copy-paste of above, everything is quite similar and.... it does not work! :(

I am quite sure that it must be something wrong with my grammar.. To be honest, I am not an expert of spirit. Here's the grammar:

```
expression = factor > * ( (char_('+')|char_('-')) > factor ) ;
factor %= uint_ | my_var | my_dat | my_rec_exp;
//   factor %= uint_ | my_var | my_dat; //this WORKS! I've made procedures to traverse an AST
// strings and ints are parsed and stored well inside the expression structure
//  factor %= uint_ | my_rec_exp; // even this simple version (of course I adjust a stucture s_expression) doesn't work.. WHY? :( , it's even less complex than loop-statement
my_rec_exp = '(' > expression > ')'; 
my_var %= char_('!') >> lexeme[+  (  char_ - ( ('+')|char_('-')|char_('*')|char_('/')|char_('(')|char_(')') )   ) ] ;
my_dat %= char_('#') >> lexeme[+  (  char_ - ( ('+')|char_('-')|char_('*')|char_('/')|char_('(')|char_(')') )   ) ] ;
```

Structures are here:
struct s_expression;

```
typedef boost::variant<
       boost::recursive_wrapper<s_expression>,
//   s_expression,
   std::string,
       unsigned int
>
s_factor;

struct s_term{ // WE DO NOT USE THIS IN THE SIMPLIFIED VERSION
    s_factor factor0;
    std::vector<std::pair<char, s_factor> > 
    factors;
};

struct s_expression{
    s_factor term0;
    std::vector<std::pair<char, s_factor> >
     terms;
};
```

I will say one more time that without recursive expression it works well (parses to en expression containing a set of numers / strings connected with operators + / - ). But if I add expression as a variant of factor it crashes on exec.

Thank you for any advice / suggestion !

Comment: I recommend that you post a compilable example with #ifdef's that demonstrate the simple, working case and the recursive, failing runtime case.  In your OP, I don't even know what you are passing into the parser!